connect new k8s installation to old persistent volumes
We run k8s in a VM (k3s actually) with a persistent volume attached and we put all of our PVs on that persistent volume. Then we install 4 applications using helm and they create 20+ PVs on that persistent volume.
Now we are contemplating disaster recover scenarios.
Is it possible to spin up a new VM and attach it to the same persistent volume and reconnect k8s to those PVs so that we ran those helm installs again, they would connect to the old PVs instead of creating new one? I understand how PVCs and PVs work. I'm wondering how k8s will recognize that there are PVs on that persistent volume already.
